# How to call specific rows from file through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
Get-Content "appetest.txt" |
    Select-Object -Index (10,20) |
    Set-Content appetest10_new2.txt
```

I need to get the range of lines, but above function is giving only specific lines 10 and 20 only.

I need to copy line from 10 through 20.

Comment: `10,20` -> `10..20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the range operator to produce a sequence of numbers.

The following should produce the output your after

```
Get-Content "appetest.txt" | 
  Select-Object -Index (10..20) |
  Set-Content appetest10_new2.txt
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
Get-Content "appetest.txt" | 
  Select-Object -Index (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) |
  Set-Content appetest10_new2.txt
```