# powershell Can you make Get-Content concise?. script

Tags: powershell

[How to call specific rows from file through PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468632/how-to-call-specific-rows-from-file-through-powershell)

`out.csv` file.

I want to divide from 1 to 1000...

And I want to arrange this in the order 1,2,3,4...

Can it be done simply?

```
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (1..1000) |set-content out_1.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (1001..2000) |set-content out_2.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (2001..3000) |set-content out_3.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (3001..4000) |set-content out_4.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (4001..5000) |set-content out_5.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (5001..6000) |set-content out_6.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (6001..7000) |set-content out_7.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (7001..8000) |set-content out_8.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (8001..9000) |set-content out_9.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (9001..10000) |set-content out_10.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (10001..11000) |set-content out_11.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (11001..12000) |set-content out_12.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (12001..13000) |set-content out_13.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (13001..14000) |set-content out_14.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (14001..15000) |set-content out_15.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (15001..16000) |set-content out_16.csv
Get-Content "out.csv" | Select-Object -Index (16001..17000) |set-content out_17.csv
```

I wrote it, but this seems too ignorant.

How many lines of script can it be expressed?.

.

The goal is to go into another script.

Preparations for multiple runs.

And my next question...

I need to run a separate list ip through powershell.

I'm thinking of opening several new windows.

I heard that distributed processing like that is faster.

Running it as one process takes a long time.

It would be nice if you could advise on this method as well.

thank you.

The end goal I'm going to put the file here.

Each file will run as a process with its own window, i.e. multiple processes.

This is done to speed up processing.

I'm still imagining I'm a beginner, so I don't know the commands, so I need to find out.

```
$ports=get-content \out_1.csv
Foreach($port in $ports){
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'A HTTP-Inbound' -Profile any -Direction Inbound -Action Block -RemoteAddress $port | Out-Null
}
```

`out.txt = out.csv`

Comment: The next question should be asked in a new question. As for your initial question, the Csv chunks will loose the headers from the original Csv are you Ok with that ?

Comment: I use a distributed 1000 lines of text. `out_1.csv` My question was too subjective so I wrote more. The AI warned me while writing the question that my question would be closed.

Comment: My first advise would be, you have 2 questions here, you should ask 2 questions (separated). As for my previous comment, if this is a Csv, the first line (the headers) do you want them on each chunk of the files or not?

Comment: And it doesn't matter if it's not `csv`. Originally, this document was a `txt` document.

Comment: I changed it to `csv` because there was an error when registering `New-Net Firewall Rule`. It doesn't matter if you change it again later. I don't know much about Heather.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm communicating through Google Translator. I don't understand more because I'm a computer beginner I'm sorry. I don't understand the text.

Comment: But to tell you what I think. My goal is to print out 1000 txt files separately.
Each file must be different. And the numbers have to be different in order

Comment: The file contains an ip address inside. Address to block  [link](https://github.com/oklokl/advfirewall-ip-list-firehol_level1.netset/blob/main/99.bat)  They say I made it. I spent a lot of time... I'm trying to shorten it.

Answer (score 5):

To **split a text file into chunks (number of lines) of a given size**, using **output files that contain a padded sequence number**, use the following:

- Note: I'm using `.txt` as the filename extension to make it clear that simple *plain-text* processing occurs; CSV files (`.csv`) would require more complex processing, because only the *first* output file would include the *header* row (containing the column names) with this approach, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out.

```bash
# Split input file out.txt into files out_01.txt, out_02.txt, ...
# with each output file containing (at most) 1000 lines.
$ndx = 0
Get-Content out.txt -ReadCount 1000 | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Content -LiteralPath ('out_{0:00}.txt' -f ++$ndx) -Value $_
}
```

Note the use of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-ReadCount` parameter, which makes it read the input file into *arrays* of lines of the given size.